# Laravel 4 Form::select adding a selected attributes

Tags: forms, laravel, select

I'm building a select options with the name of Position. I'm wondering on how to add a selected attributes on the last row.

```
{{ Form::label('position', 'Position') }}
{{ Form::select('position', array(0 => 'Please Choose') + range(0,$position + 1) ) }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to the function is the currently selected value, so in your case you should be able to insert `$position + 1` there.

```
{{ Form::select('position', array(0 => 'Please Choose') + range(0,$position + 1), $position + 1) }}
```